# Getting "Remote to remote not supported" when copy file from Windows host to remote Ubuntu server using pscp

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp, pscp

I'm trying to copy a file from a Windows host to a remote Linux (Ubuntu) server using `pscp`.

This looks straight forward at first:

```
pscp -P 22 'C:\text.txt' user@ip:~/Downloads
```

However, I get the following error:

> 'C:\test.txt': Remote to remote not supported

The thing is I found nothing about *"remote to remote not supported"*. I mean, really nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes around `C:\text.txt` should not be there.

- Either remove them, as no quotes are needed, if the path does not contain spaces.

  ```
  pscp C:\text.txt user@ip:~/Downloads
  ```
- Or use double-quotes.

  ```
  pscp "C:\path with spaces\text.txt" user@ip:~/Downloads
  ```

Single quotes are rarely used in Windows commandline.

*Also the `-P 22` is not needed either, as port 22 is the default SSH/SFTP/SCP port.*